# Can't read in a long cin input to a string

Tags: c++, string, cin

I have code that looks like this

```
string inputString;
std::getline (std::cin, inputString)
cout << inputString;
```

when I cin a long string ~30k characters then inputString only has part of that string. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure it does not contain the full input?  If you output `inputString.size()` what do you get?

Comment: Might the size be limited by the max allowed line length of your terminal?

Comment: Can you add an example input that causes this issue, and the output it generates?  It might help determine the problem.

Comment: For sure try to std::getline() once again... see if the remainder of the text gets read the second time...

Comment: inputString.size() = 4905, well below the full text. I did a getline again and it didn't automatically get new text.
I tried different texts and still capped at 4905 for some reason.

Comment: turns out it's a weird terminal limit. Could be solved with stty -icanon

Answer (score 0):

From the `std::getline()` documentation on  [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

> `getline` reads characters from an input stream and places them into a string:
>
> 1. Behaves as `UnformattedInputFunction`, except that `input.gcount()` is not affected. After constructing and checking the sentry object, performs the following:
>
> 1. Calls `str.erase()`
> 2. Extracts characters from `input` and appends them to `str` until one of the following occurs (checked in the order listed)
>
>    a. end-of-file condition on `input`, in which case, `getline` sets `eofbit`.
>
>    b. the next available input character is `delim`, as tested by `Traits::eq(c, delim)`, in which case the delimiter character is extracted from `input`, but is not appended to `str`.
>
>    c. **`str.max_size()` characters have been stored, in which case `getline` sets `failbit` and returns**.
> 3. If no characters were extracted for whatever reason (not even the discarded delimiter), `getline` sets `failbit` and returns.
>
> 2. Same as `getline(input, str, input.widen('\n'))`, that is, the default delimiter is the endline character.

So check to see if your input is being limited by the value of `inputString.max_size()`.  It might be near 32k on your system.

Comment: Or maybe 16k if Turbo C++ :D

Comment: Hmm, no, max_size() is a huge size of 4294967295

Answer (score 0):

By default, the terminal works in canonical mode, and it has a buffer of the length 4096 Bytes. So that's why the maximum input that the string can take is 4095. Now the solution is to change to the noncanonical mode in Linux. You can do so by

```
$ stty -icanon # for switching to the noncanonical mode.
$ stty icanon  # reverting back to the canonical mode when you are done.
```